# java.sql.SQLException: unsupported feature: refreshrow

Tags: oracle, jdbc

//SensitiveTest.java

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
class SensitiveTest
{

public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception
{

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl1","scott","password");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
    int count=0;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        rs.refreshRow();
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getInt(6));
        count++;
    if(count==2)
    {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    }
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();

}

}
```

it shows the compile error java.sql.SQLException: unsupported feature: refreshrow  how can i solve this problem

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to call this method at all ? Anyway, JDBC specification says that this is optiona feature and JDBC driver needn't implement it, the error simply says `We are sorry, we have not impemented that method in our driver, please don't call it because it wont work`

Comment: Why are you calling `refreshRow()` in the first place? It is totally useless and makes no sense in the code you have shown.

Comment: Suppose i have table on database that table contain some records after display the two records sleep some time than during this if i change any modification on database table it will display changes done on table ,that's why i was used     refreshRow() to refresh ResultSet interface object